# Combining variable and html inside a PHP variable

Tags: php

The code below is generating a result like this: `http://localhost/my_website/ contact-us`

```
$base_url="http://localhost/my_website/";
echo $link= "$base_url contact-us ";
```

But I am trying to get a result like this : `http://localhost/my_website/contact-us`

I have also tried the following code

```
$base_url="http://localhost/my_website/";
echo $link= "$base_url.contact-us ";
```

but the result is like this `http://localhost/my_website/.contact-us`

Could you please show me how to solve this problem?

## Edit

I am very sorry, I did't clearly mention the exact problem I am facing here. I thought the above example would help my case. Actually I am trying to create a link that I will send at users email address.

My code

```
$base_url="http://localhost/my_website/";
$random_hash="1";
echo $link="
<a href='$base_url account/confirm_registration/$random_hash' target='_blank'>$base_url   account/confirm_registration/$random_hash</a>";
```

But it is generating like this

```
http://localhost/my_website/ account/confirm_registration/1
```

Comment: You don't understand how to use the concatenation character `.`: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I visited the link and found a solution. I am using {} like this {$base_url}account/...  and it is working perfectly. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo $link = $base_url."contact-us";
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, please check the edited part of my question

Comment: echo '<a href="'.$base_url.'contact-us">'.$base_url.'</a>'; // just take your variables out of quotes.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your code works but I have found a better solution :) I am using `{}` like this `{$base_url}account/...`

Comment: It is not better solution although it works. "$var" is slower then $var.

Answer (score 0):

```
$base_url="http://localhost/my_website/";
echo $link= $base_url."contact-us";
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to split it

Tested and works:

```
$base_url="http://localhost/my_website/"; 

echo $link=$base_url."contact-us";
```

Comment: You don't need the quotes around `$base_url`.

Comment: And then your answer becomes identical with already existing answers... :)

Comment: Yes but when I wrote it there was still no other answers :/

Answer (score 0):

```
$base_url="http://localhost/my_website/";
$link=$base_url."contact-us";
echo $link;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about basic string concatenation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Try this:

```
$base_url = "http://localhost/my_website/";
$random_hash = "1";
$url_page = "account/confirm_registration/$random_hash";
$url = $base_url . $url_page;
$link = "<a href='$url'>$url</a>";

echo $link;
```